# How to concatenate csv files with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, concatenation

I am working on datas and I want to merge/concatenate some csv files.
I tried the code below but there is a problem, I've got the error message below when I run the script. It seems that it can't read my files.

NB : My scrypt is located in the same place as my csv files.

How can I fix it up ?

Thanks !!!

I'm working on windows and using anaconda with Spyder. It runs python 3.7

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

L_Log= os.listdir('.')

L_LogClean=[]

for k in range(len(L_Log)):
    if 'Logfile_' in L_Log[k]:
        Tempo = L_Log[k]
        Tempo2 = Tempo[12:16]+Tempo[10:12]+Tempo[8:10]
        Tempo2 = int(Tempo2)
        L_LogClean.append(Tempo2)
        L_LogClean = sorted(L_LogClean)

for k in range(len(L_LogClean)):
    Tempo = str(L_LogClean[k])
    Tempo2 = 'Logfile_' + Tempo[6:8]+Tempo[4:6]+Tempo[0:4]+'.csv'
    L_LogClean[k] = Tempo2
    print(L_LogClean)


dfList=[]
colnames=['No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temps2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_LogClean:
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None)
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat.csv')
```

I expect a csv file that will be the concatenation of the differents files ordered by their name. 
When I run the script, it shows me this error message :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Logfile_13052019.csv' does not exist: b'Logfile_13052019.csv'
```

But my file Logfile_13052019.csv do is in the same folder as the script

UPDATE :

```py
dfList=[]
colnames=['No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temps2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat.csv')
```

I edited my code and got this error

```py
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 22 elements
```

Still blocked on this script

UPDATE 2

```py
I added the separator type on my script :
dfList=[]
colnames=['No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temps2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, sep = ";", error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat.csv')
```

But I still have as error the following message :

```py
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 25 elements, new values have 22 elements
```

Update 3 :
I changed this part

```py
dfList=[]
colnames=['bite','No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temp2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité Relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp2_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, sep = ";", error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat2.csv')
```

I got a concatenated file at the end but each line when I open it with excel i has something like that in the very first cell of each row :
1,1,13.05.2019,00:01:21,"18,16",Â°C,"12,00",Â°C,"1,00",Lux,0,37,%,487,ppm,0,"18,04",Â°C,"18,20",Â°C,"17,76",Â°C,"37,20",%,0,

[Result of merging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqkBZ.png)

But the sheet should look like that :
[Normal form of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYajE.png)

Answer (score 0):

How many files are you reading and is your code working for other files and  failing only for this one? Or is this the first file you are reading and it is failing?

The error looks pretty simple that the code is not able to locate the file. Try to load the file separately in terminal and see what happens. If it doesn't work,  provide the full path of the file and then read it. Make sure that the file name is an exact match as these paths are case sensitive.

Update:

```
for filename in L_LogClean:
    filename = complete_path_of_directory + filename
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None)
    dfList.append(df)
```

Update 2:

```
dfList=[]
colnames=['No.','Date','Time','Temp1','Unit','Temps2','Unit','Lux2','Unit','BP1','Humidité relat','Unit','CO2','Unit','Présence','Temp1_EnO','Unit','Temp3_EnO','Unit','RH3_EnO','Unit','Chauffage']
for filename in L_Log:
    filename = "E://PJT/TEST2/" + filename
    print(filename)
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,header=None, sep = ";", error_bad_lines=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pd.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv('Concat.csv')
```

Comment: Your working directory is different then the files directory. In the code, append the exact working directory to the file name

Comment: I Tried your solution and got another eeror, i posted the modified scrypt and the error message below as I don't know well how to comment your answer. Thanks !

Comment: Check what is the value separator in your csv file. I think it is not a comma.

Comment: It is a ";" I found it by opening my csv file with the native notepad of windows

Comment: I have updated the answer. read_csv by default has the separator set to ",". If you have a different separator in your data, you need to specify it using `sep = `

Comment: I used sep =  but it's still not working (I updated a second time my first post)

Comment: Now your dataframe has 25 columns in total. When you are setting column names, you are sending a list of 22 columns. That is causing the error. Update your `colnames` list to have 25 column names.

Comment: I did i and got a concatenated file ! But the data are stranges sadly. Here is a link where you can find one of my original csv file and the result of the concatenation : [files used for the concatenation](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/vib9x8e20shv57v,virdb4sjvcu5u5n/shared)

Comment: Sorry but I wont be able to open the file on my system. If you can explain what that strange is, I will be able to help. If you are able to read the data, then something is wrong either with data or concat. Make sure all the log files have same column order and your concat is running correctly

Comment: Something looks wrong with the encoding and data. The code seems fine to me. Try removing the encoding and error_bad_lines or change the encoding. Also open files with a text editor to see the separators in header and in rows.